# Unable to import 3.4GB csv into redshift because values contains free-text with commas

Tags: csv, ipython, bigdata, amazon-redshift

And so we found a 3.6GB csv that we have uploaded onto S3 and now want to import into Redshift, then do the querying and analysis from iPython.

Problem 1:
This comma delimited file contains values free text that also contains commas and this is interfering with the delimiting so can’t upload to Redshift.
When we tried opening the sample dataset in Excel, Excel surprisingly puts them into columns correctly.

Problem 2: 
A column that is supposed to contain integers have some records containing alphabets to indicate some other scenario.
So, the only way to get the import through is to declare this column as varchar. But then we can do calculations later on.

Problem 3:
The datetime data type requires the date time value to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, but the csv doesn’t contain the SS and the database is rejecting the import.

We can’t manipulate the data on a local machine because it is too big, and we can’t upload onto the cloud for computing because it is not in the correct format.
The last resort would be to scale the instance running iPython all the way up so that we can read the big csv directly from S3, but this approach doesn’t make sense as a long-term solution.

Your suggestions?

- Train: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketbigdataclass/stack_overflow_train.csv (3.4GB)
- Train Sample: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucketbigdataclass/stack_overflow_train-sample.csv (133MB)

Comment: Problem 3: Add the `:SS` back then. Few lines of codes will do the trick in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having different delimiter or use escape characters.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_preparing_data.html

For second issue, if you want to extract only numbers from the column after loading into char use regexp_replace or other functions.

For third issue, you can as well load it into VARCHAR field and then use substring `cast(left(column_name, 10)||' '||right(column_name, 6)||':00' as timestamp)`

to load it into final table from staging table

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, you need to find out a way to differentiate between the two types of commas - the delimiter and the text commas. Once you have done that, replace the delimiters with a different delimiter and use the same as delimiter in the copy command for Redshift.

For the second issue, you need to first figure out if this column needs to be present for numerical aggregations once loaded. If yes, you need to get this data cleaned up before loading. If no, you can directly load this as char/ varchar field. All your queries will still work but you will not be able to do any aggregations (sum/ avg and the likes) on this field.

For problem 3, you can use Text(date, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") function in excel to do a mass replace for this field.

Let me know if this works out.

Comment: What exactly would you do to do the replacement of commas? I can't clean up the data or apply the date function in Excel because the file is too big to be loaded. It contains many millions of rows.